# Javascript Amcharts Trimming "$" or "&" values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, amcharts

I am using Javascript amcharts to display PIE chart.
below is my code

```
    var settings ={ autoMargins:false,
                    "[[label]] : [[text]]",
                    dataProvider:[{borderColor: "#A3B865", color: "#9BD786", text: "374.84 KB", value: 383841, label: "प्रोफाईल1$&)$&_#&%DDSS%20%25"}{borderColor: "#BF5F47", color: "#E28162", text: "372.88 KB", value: 381833, label: "Default"}],
                    labelText:"[[text]]",
                    labelsEnabled:false,
                    startDuration:0,
                    titleField:"label",
                    type:"pie",
                    urlField:"url",
                    valueField:"value"}
    var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("#chart", settings);
    chart.write("#chart");
```

I am providing name as "प्रोफाईल1$&)$&*#&%DDSS%20%25" but on hover pie chart the label is displayed with trimmed value it displays "प्रोफाईल1)&*#&%DDSS%20%25" it removes first 2 "$" chars and 1 "&".
I am not able to analylize why its remove those chars.
If i use "प्रोफाईल1$$$$$$" then also it will trim down first 2 "$" chars.
[image]

can anyone help to resolve the problem

[image]

Comment: At a guess, you probably need to mark them up.

Comment: @pareshm - This looks like a bug. I've forwarded it to the AmCharts team to investigate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is problem with amcharts library
tried with there live editor also problem persists
check the Default 1 value on hovering it
it trims 1 "$"

Example https://live.amcharts.com/MGJhY/edit/